# Resource recommendation for learning matter modeling for a novice

Tags: density-functional-theory, computational-chemistry, software, monte-carlo, dynamical-mean-field-theory

I am a starting researcher in condensed matter physics. Hence, i have all the necessary background regarding quantum physics, and condensed matter physics. But what i want to do is to learn different computational approaches for numerical simulations used in condensed matter physics. Specifically, i will like to learn following approaches for starters:

1. Density Functional theory calculations
2. Mote-Carlo simulations (Classical and Quantum)
3. Dynamic Mean field theory
4. Local Density Approximation + Dynamic Mean field Theory

I will really appreciate the help from this community, for guidance in learning above methods and beyond. Specifically, i will like if anyone can suggest:

1. Books
2. Tutorials or Lectures
3. Software packages (i have heard of VASP and QE, but as i want to understand the working of the physics and mathematics, hence i will like to at first code pedagogical examples in python and then jump to individual packages for real researches)

P.S. I have started to listen lectures from Kristjan Haule (https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/grad/509/) from Rutgers university. After completing this what should i learn? As he only teaches DFT for simple atoms and classical Mote-Carlo simulations in this lecture series.

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you haven't yet, try searching the site for [resources](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/search?q=resources). There are a number of  prior questions looking for specific or general resources related to learning matter modeling.

Comment: @Tyberius thank you very much for the tip.

Comment: This question is extremely broad. Please narrow it down to one thing.